# Bluetooth headphones are cutting out a lot

Tags: bluetooth, mac-mini, headphones

I have Sony WH-1000XM3 Bluetooth headphones and they are cutting out frequently when I'm more than 1m away from my Mac Mini 2018. Disabling WiFi on Mac helps a little but the problem still persists.

Comment: Are you using any other devices with Bluetooth like keyboard, mouse, trackpad etc.?

Comment: No, I use no other BT devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what helped me was [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251275864).

I have a USB hub connected to my Mac, after wrapping all the cables in the aluminum foil, the problem was solved!

[image: cables connected to Mac Mini wrapped with aluminum foil on the connectors]